# Adding subscript with different font inside a span

Tags: html, css, html-table, subscript

I'm displaying a percentage in my website like **44%**. Both value and subscript are of different font. The subscript is not coming correctly.

I'm sharing the code below:

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>
    <div style='display:block;'>
 <span style='font-size: 220px;line-height: 200px;'>44
            <span style='font-size:20px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;'><sup>%</sup>
 </span>
 </span>
  </div>
</b>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want the percentage symbol just above and very close to the value. Now there is lot of space between the value and % symbol. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding `line-height` to the `<sup>` as well.

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>
    <div style='display:block;'>
 <span><span style='font-size: 220px;line-height: 200px;'>
  44<sup style='vertical-align:top;font-size:20px;line-height: 50px;'>%</sup></span>
 </span>
  </div>
</b>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```